# get large number of Post values

Tags: python, tornado

```
class MergeHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):        
    def post(self):
        noun1 = self.get_argument('noun1')
        noun2 = self.get_argument('noun2')
        noun3 = self.get_argument('noun3')
        noun4 = self.get_argument('noun4')
        noun5 = self.get_argument('noun5')
        ...
        noun25 = self.get_argument('noun25')

        sys.exit()
```

I have multiples inputs, and i don't know exactly how many. Even If I known, is really annoying do

`nounX = self.get_argument('nounX')` every time for each input received.

Does anyone know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def post(self):
    var_dump({ k: self.get_argument(k) for k in self.request.arguments })
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing repetitive tasks like this it is almost always possible to use a loop:

```
def post(self):
    NUM_NOUNS_EXPECTED = 25
    nouns = {}
    for i in range(1, NUM_NOUNS_EXPECTED + 1):
        key = 'noun{}'.format(i)
        nouns[key] = self.get_argument(key)
```

---

```
def post(self):
    required_params = ['something', 'again', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'smile', 'here']
    for param in required_params:
        self.get_argument(param)
```

Comment: ok, but if i have a input name with a different name than nounX?

Comment: At some point I believe you need to know your input names to validate them, you can list them as a list, and at least minimize the lines of code involved, updating answer

Comment: Apparently is really simple.   print( self.request.arguments) will get all post values. For me will work. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
parameters = dict() 
for k in request.arguments.iterkeys(): 
  parameters[k] = self.get_argument(k, strip=False)
```

Source: http://vmiroshnikov.com/post/33383858889/make-tornado-keep-blank-values-in-request-arguments